# Copying a file from a remote server

Tags: c#, file-io, file-copying

What I am trying to do is copying a file from a remote PC folder which is not shared. 
I wrote a code to connect to the PC using ManagementScope i executed some WMI queries in order to ensure that i am connected. Now the problem is when i execute the `File.Copy()` function as

```
File.Copy(@"\\Source_server\\C:\Users\ku\Desktop\test1.txt", @"\\Destination_server\\C:\Users\mo\Downloads\");
```

it shows me

> Path format not supported

Does `File.Copy` doesn't support file copy on network??
Is there any other method to do that??

(I have the user name and password of the remote PC)
-Thanks for the reply in advance

Comment: Why do you have C:\ in your path?

Comment: Are you sure about the name of the share ? "C:" isn't a valid name. Also, the double backslash should only be at the beginning of the path.

Comment: The answer on Extracting a file from remote server also has an answer but it needs to be a shared folder there..

But by just making few changes in the path as suggested by Casperah it works for unshared folder too..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use this path:

```
\\Source_server\C$\Users\ku\Desktop\test1.txt
```

But that would require administrator rights on your server.

A better solution would be to create a shared folder on the server and use that for reading and writting files.